# Pale colors in vim in xterm on OpenSuSE with esckeys

Tags: vim, opensuse

Consider the following setting. A Vim (>= 7.3) editor being started in an xterm with dark background and Vim settings `background=dark`, `syn on` and initially `noesckeys`. Due to the setting of dark background and enabled syntax highlighting, keywords are highlighted with bright and bold colors. Now if I issue `:set esckeys` (either via .vimrc or interactively) and am on OpenSuSE (12.3) all colors become pale (but something different to `background=light`) either instantly or after a few key presses. I cannot reproduce this behavior on any Debian system. Now unfortunately I do want to set esckeys, because it is useful with latexsuite.

What is the cause for this weired behavior or how can I determine the cause?

Is there any workaround available to use bold colors and esckeys at the same time?

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue, please state your configuration (Vim version, OS) as a comment.

Comment: What @helmut said but as *an edit* to your question (not a comment).

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be tough, so let's develop a community wiki answer together.

The origin of the initial color scheme is not entirely clear. A look at `:scriptnames` with `--noplugins` gives an idea of where it may come from:

```
  1: /etc/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim
  6: ~/.vimrc
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/nosyntax.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim73/indent.vim
```

The only file that contains color definitions is `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syncolor.vim`. It contains definitions that have `term=bold` or `term=underline` and `cterm=NONE` for most highlights when `&background == "dark"`. A guess is that Vim initially uses the `term` attributes. Why?

With the `esckeys` setting Vim re-initializes the terminal after a (e.g. movement) key is pressed. Specifically it issues an escape sequence that clears the screen and redraws everything. Why?

During re-initialization apparently it does `syntax on` again thus indirectly invoking `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syncolor.vim` again (strace shows the file is read again). At this point Vim is clearly using the `cterm` attributes and clears all the boldness attributes explaining the observation.

As a workaround adding a custom colorscheme with matching boldness attributes can avoid flash of colors while still doing the reinitialization.